# Possible to link mouse buttons to macOS functions

Tags: mouse, desktop, automation

I've just taken delivery of a new mechanical keyboard and laser mouse as I wanted to switch off the Bluetooth on my MacBook Pro (early 2013 Retina, running High Sierra).

All is working nicely with the Mac except I've lost the gesture control which I use a lot to switch between VMware virtual machines.

The laser mouse is a gaming mouse ([HyperX Puslefire FPS](https://www.scan.co.uk/products/hyperx-pulsefire-fps-gaming-mouse-optical-red-back-lit-400-800-1600-3200dpi-wired-usb-6-buttons-1000?v=c)) with a couple of extra buttons and I'd like to assign these buttons to switch desktops.

Does anyone know how I can do this, ideally without 3rd party software, using automation or similar?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you preferring to have to use 3rd party software at all, or just not having to pay for it? Also, can I suggest you edit your question to include the model details of the gaming mouse in question and the version of macOS you're running?

Comment: I'd prefer not to have any 3rd party software at all; but I'd like to know if that is the only option

Comment: 3rd party software is a necessity here.  You can't reassign mouse buttons, especially the *custom* ones on a gaming mouse without it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's no doubt possible to map your mouse buttons to Keyboards keys, but considering the generic nature of your mouse, I'm doubtful you'd be able to do it without 3rd party software.

While I haven’t used these to map buttons to a HyperX Pulsefire FPS gaming mouse, I have used these to map the buttons from a variety of other controllers:

- [USB Overdrive](http://www.usboverdrive.com/USBOverdrive/News.html)
- [ControllerMate](https://www.orderedbytes.com/controllermate/)

I’d start with USB Overdrive as it offers a much simpler interface. ControllerMate provides a lot more advanced functionality, but also takes quite some time to suss out.

Now, I haven't used [SensibleSideButtons](http://sensible-side-buttons.archagon.net/), but that may work in your scenario if the extra buttons are side buttons. Nor have I used [Steer Mouse](http://plentycom.jp/en/steermouse/), but I know of people who swear by it.

Comment: Understood, thanks for your help.  I went with the USB Overdrive